# Save picture from Camera/Gallery picker into folder, and load that picture in an image view in a different activity?

Tags: android, image, uri, image-gallery

Alright so I'm trying to achieve something that shouldn't be that difficult but for some reason or another it is. So I have an app that goes through a setup process where it asks for your name and then two ID numbers and all this is saved in shared preferences and no matter if a reboot or force close the app the data is kept. Third step in the setup process includes getting a picture from the user, and I have successfully gotten it to show up once but it doesn't stick after a reboot or force close. So my question is what code do I need to open the gallery picker intent so the user can choose a photo, save that photo, write that Uri to the photo in a string, and then proceed to enter it into a SharedPreference so it sticks across reboot/ force close. I had the code working but it wouldn't save the Uri in the correct manner so therefore it wouldn't load. But I scraped all this code in hopes someone can give me a more direct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most `Uri` values are transient and are not guaranteed to be usable minutes after you get them, let alone forever.

Your choices are:

1. If your `minSdkVersion` is 19+, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to pick the image. The Storage Access Framework has an option for [persistent `Uri` permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#permissions), with a side effect of having a more durable `Uri`. Even then, though, since the user might get rid of the image, you cannot assume that you will have access to it forever.
2. Copy the image into your own app and use your local copy.

Comment: So if I wanted to do option number 2 what code can I use to do that?

Comment: @SkylerMartin: Call `getContentResolver()` on some `Context` (e.g., your `Activity`) to get a `ContentResolver`. Call `openInputStream()` on the `ContentResolver`, passing in your `Uri`, to get an `InputStream` on the image. Use standard Java I/O to read from the `InputStream` and write to some `FileOutputStream` that you set up for wherever you want to store your copy (e.g., [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)).